# Как создать анимацию перемещения обьекта tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, анимация

Никак не могу создать функцию для анимации объекта. Надо, что бы она перемещалась от начальной точки, до конечной, которые указываются кликом мышки по полотну.

Изначально пробовал использовать matplotlib в интерфейсе tkinter(в задании указано использовать какой-то интерфейс, по этому так странно), но там тоже беда с анимацией, никак не мог разобраться. Решил попробовать сразу в tkinter`е сделать, теперь просто не могу написать функцию для плавного перемещения от одной точки к другой. Может кто-то поможет, или скажет где лучше выполнить это.

Вот как должна выглядеть анимация:

[image: Вот пример анимации, которая должна быть]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Tkinter settings
root.geometry ('400x400')
 
# Creating canvas and OX and OY axis
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 400, height = 400,bg = 'white')
canvas.grid(column = 4, row = 6)
canvas.create_line(200,400,200,0,width=2,arrow=LAST)
canvas.create_line(0,200,400,200,width=2,arrow=LAST)


mss_x,mss_y = [],[] #cordinates of all x`s` and y`s` separetly
coords= [] #cordinates of start and end

# To create circle
def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName): 
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

# To get coordinates from click and draw bresenham line
def callback(event):
    if len(coords)<4:
        coords.append(int(event.x))   
        coords.append(int(event.y))
    if len(coords)==4:
        DrawLine(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3])

# Function to draw current pixel
def draw_pixel(mss_x,mss_y, i):
    return canvas.create_rectangle(mss_x[i-1], mss_y[i-1], mss_x[i-1], mss_y[i-1], fill="red", outline="red")

# Bresenham algorithm
def DrawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dx = abs(x2-x1)
    dy = abs(y2-y1)

    x=x1
    y=y1

    xs = 1 if x<x2 else -1
    ys = 1 if y<y2 else -1

    if dx>dy:
        p=2*dy-dx 
        while x!=x2:
            x=x+xs
            if p > 0:
                y=y+ys
                p=p+2*dy-2*dx
            else:
                p=p+2*dy
            mss_x.append(x)
            mss_y.append(y)

    else:
        p=2*dx-dy
        while y!=y2:
            y+=ys
            if p > 0:
                x+=xs
                p+=2*dx-2*dy
            else:
                p+=2*dx
            mss_x.append(x)
            mss_y.append(y)
    
    for i in range(len(mss_x)):
        draw_pixel(mss_x,mss_y,i)


def Animation(mss_x,mss_y):
    c = create_circle(mss_x[0],mss_y[0], 7,canvas)
    for i in range(len(mss_x)):
        canvas.move(c, mss_x[i-1], mss_y[i-1])
        i+=1
        # while i < len(mss_x):
        #     canvas.move(c, mss_x[i-1], mss_y[i-1])
        #     root.after(40)
        #     i-=1

root.bind('<Button 1>',callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А ручная реализация рисования линии нужна по заданию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант реализации: берем координаты начала и конца, определяем длину отрезка, исходя из нужной длины шага считаем на какую долю от полного вертикального и горизонтального перемещения нужно сместиться на каждом шаге, далее через метод `after` планируем выполнение функции, которая фактически перемещает ваш кружок.

```
def callback(event):
    if len(coords)<4:
        coords.append(int(event.x))   
        coords.append(int(event.y))
    if len(coords)==4:
        DrawLine(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3])
        Animation(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3])


...


def Animation(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    length = (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** .5
    step = 10  # перемещение вдоль линии на 10 пикселей за раз
    step_x = step / length * dx
    step_y = step / length * dy
    
    r = 7
    c = create_circle(x1, y1, r, canvas)
    
    progress = 0
    
    def animate():
        nonlocal progress
        progress += step
        if progress < length:
            canvas.move(c, step_x, step_y)  # Относительное смещение на step_x, step_y
            root.after(40, animate)  # Планируем выполнение функции animate через 40ms
        else:
            # Последнее перемещение делаем точно на конец отрезка
            canvas.coords(c, x2-r, y2-r, x2+r, y2+r)
    
    animate()
```

[image: Анимация]